# Applying a JSON path with an expression filter to a non-array JSON element with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

I am trying to apply an JSON Path that only selects elements based on another element in the document.

For example, for the following JSON:

```
{
    'SomeFieldA': 'X',
    'SomeFieldB': {
         'SomeFieldC': 'Y'
     }
}
```

I want to only select `SomeFieldC` when `SomeFieldA` exists and is equal to `X`

I've tried running the following expression `$.SomeFieldB[?($.SomeFieldA == 'X')].SomeFieldC` and even though it works in some implementations (e.g. https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/), it doesn't seem to work with Newtonsoft (JSON.NET)

The following code doesn't work for me (returns an empty list):

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(@"
    {
        'SomeFieldA': 'X',
        'SomeFieldB': {
            'SomeFieldC': 'Y'

        }
    }");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    jsonObject.SelectTokens("$.SomeFieldB[?($.SomeFieldA == 'X')].SomeFieldC")
        .Select(token => token.ToString())));
```

I know I can get this behavior with a simple LINQ query, but I have a framework that can only work with JSON paths and so I want to find a JSON path that will accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that Newtonsoft doesn't like the `$` inside the filter expression.  This doesn't seem to be tested in the [implementation comparison project](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/).

We *have* decided it's valid to use it, however, as part of the [effort to standardize JSON Path](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base).

If you need a .Net implementation that supports this, check out my [JsonPath.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonPath.Net/).

If you're stuck with Newtonsoft, try https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonPath/ instead.  No guarantees on it though.

Comment: Sounds like I can't really do it without migrating everything from `Newtonsoft` to `System.Text.Json` huh

Comment: Seems that as of .NET 5 `System.Text.Json` does not support modification of JSONs, which an unrelated requirement of mine, so it's not a viable option

Comment: You _can_ get the effect of modifying JSON, but it has to be through repeated stringifying and parsing, which is what my library does for now.  `JsonNode` is a concept that should come with .Net 6.

Comment: Internally to my JsonPatch.Net, I define an `EditableJsonElement` that I use to track the changes before constructing the final output.  You can view the source at https://www.github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything/tree/master/JsonPatch%2FEditableJsonElement.cs.  There's also a helper class for it.

Comment: If edited the answer with another option that uses Newtonsoft.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I think editing a JSON like that will probably be too inefficient for my case (a high scale data pipeline). Will consider moving once .NET 6 releases in November.

Comment: In the meantime for documentation's sake - I changed my flow to run separate JSON paths for filtering and extraction, which is certainly not ideal, but is good enough for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to select `SomeFieldC` based on a condition `SomeFieldA == X`-

```
var result = jObject["SomeFieldA"]?.ToString() == "X" ? 
             jObject["SomeFieldB"]?["SomeFieldC"]?.ToString() : "";
```